# How to display filtered rows in aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, isnull, group-by

Given the following query:

```
    SELECT dbo.ClientSub.chk_Name as Details, COUNT(*) AS Counts
    FROM dbo.ClientMain 
      INNER JOIN 
        dbo.ClientSub 
          ON dbo.ClientMain.ate_Id = dbo.ClientSub.ate_Id 
    WHERE chk_Status=1 
    GROUP BY dbo.ClientSub.chk_Name
```

I want to display the rows in the aggregation even if  there are filtered in the WHERE clause.

Comment: In your case you will get the empty result set.

Comment: By "no values belongs to chk_Name" do you mean "no records in ClubSub for a record in ClientMain"?

Comment: @AdrianWragg: mean chk_Name is not ther with chk_Status=1. So It has to come with chk_name values with zero as Counts.

Comment: @CenBan - for future note - your question has nothing to do with null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` values are considered as zeros for aggregation purposes.

For your intention you should use `GROUP BY ALL` that returns rows which were filtered also, with zero as aggregated value.

Answer (score 0):

in case you use oracle sql:

Have you tried `Select nvl(dbo.ClientSub.chk_name,'0') ....`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? Which returns count 0 if chk_Name is NULL.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ClientSub.chk_Name as Details, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(dbo.ClientSub.chk_Name, '')<>'' then 1 else 0 end) AS Counts
FROM 
    dbo.ClientMain INNER JOIN dbo.ClientSub ON dbo.ClientMain.ate_Id = dbo.ClientSub.ate_Id 
where chk_Status=1      
group by dbo.ClientSub.chk_Name
```

Comment: sorry to say. It is not giving the null values as zero. It is working as my query only

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Don't know whether that's your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Oracle. You can directly use count(chk_name). Passing a column name in the count neglects null values. Your query above returns the total number of records against each chk_name group. When you use count(chk_name) it will count all the records where chk_name is not null.

I hope that answers your question.

Thanks,

Aditya

Comment: sorry .. I am using sql server 2005

Comment: No.. It is not working. It is not giving any value for nulls. Null record is not appearing in result